# `pwd -P` preventing bash script from running in supervisord

Tags: bash, shell, supervisord, deployment

I'm running supervisord to execute gunicorn. My problem is when my script contains CURR_DIR=`pwd -P` and run the script via supervisord, it STOPS the process. My script is located in `/var/www/conf` and I expect `pwd P` to return `/var/www/conf` when I run the script. I tried PWD and that doesn't return `/var/www/conf` either. The `pwd -P` works when I run the script outside of supervisord.

But if I hardcode CURR_DIR=/some/dir then supervisord runs the script no problem.

Here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=myproj 
GUNICORN_EXEC=/home/user/.virtualenvs/tscoop/bin/gunicorn
CURRENT_DIR=`pwd -P`      # does not work: causes "STOPPED" error in supervisord
CURRENT_DIR=/var/www/conf # works ok

export GUNICORN_CONF=${CURRENT_DIR}/gunicorn.conf

echo "Starting $NAME"

exec $GUNICORN_EXEC -c $GUNICORN_CONF

exit 0
```

Here's the error message I get from supervisorctl shell:

```
supervisor> status
myscript                            STOPPED    Aug 27 09:57 PM
```

How can I make it so that I can run supervisord can run the above script?

Comment: And I tried adding PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games.  Does not work either.

Comment: Also, I enabled bash debugging using "!#/bin/bash -x" and the logs show me when I "echo \`pwd -P`" or "echo $PWD" I only get "\". Strange.

Comment: Why do you think this is strange? What are you expecting ?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: I am expecting /var/www/conf when I have pwd -P, because the script is located in /var/www/conf. I don't know why I got a -1. I will update my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want because the value returned by [pwd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd) is not guaranteed to be what you expect.

---

The location of the script is not it's working directory

```
$cat test
#!/bin/bash
pwd

$ ./test
/home/iain

$ cd /tmp
$/home/iain/test
/tmp
```

See ? pwd is returning the current directory of the shell I used to invoke the test command. This is what is happening to you, you are seeing values inherited from supervisord.

If you read the document Dennis [links to](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) it provides useful information about how you may be able to solve your problem.